# What was this story, and why did they have heart plugs?

Tags: story-identification, movie

Many years ago, I remember seeing a film (probably a really naff low-budget SF movie), from which the only line I can remember is an evil dictator saying to a captured baddy, “I see you have a heart plug fitted. We all do eventually”. The dictator then pulled this ‘heart plug’ out, killing the baddy – it was a plug with a loop on it, to allow him to do this easily.

Does anyone know what movie this might have been?

The other question about this, which I couldn’t work out at the time, is why anyone would have something that would make it so easy to be caught and kill you?

Comment: This question was previously 'protected' because it attracted four very low quality answers. If you're planning to answer this, please check to make sure that you're adding something of value to the site.

Comment: [We don't add tags to solved question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/671/should-we-tag-solved-story-identification-questions-with-the-name-of-the-autho). It makes OP look foolish.

Comment: See also [this new Meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12285/98028) which is meant to be definitive and argues its point quite well.

Comment: <comments deleted> Take it to meta, guys.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Almost surely you mean David Lynch's version of [*Dune*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087182) (1984). The evil dictator would be the Baron Harkonnen. In the film, Harkonnens typically install "heart plugs" on their slaves in order to control them. In the book they use poisons, if I recall correctly.

This also answers your second question: nobody would accept a heart plug voluntarily, but apparently for both Harkonnens and their slaves it is mandatory. I assume they give you no options.

There is a [scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JHGITJqMbO4) *(warning: NSFW)* where the Baron kills a slave boy by popping out his heart plug, purely out of pleasure. In both the movie and the book, the Baron has sadistic sexual tendencies.

Comment: Arghhhh! The painfully bad lengths that movie directors will go to to avoid admitting that their medium doesn't deal well with novel length written works never cease to amaze me.

Comment: From that IMDB link: "Budget: $40,000,000" (in 1984). So, really really not a "low-budget SF movie", (compare $32m for Ghostbusters and $6.2m for The Terminator) although it may well have been naff.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman: indeed, it wasn't low budget. However, everything else fits, so I bet it's Lynch's Dune the OP is talking about. It isn't _naff_ either, in my opinion; it's just over the top and very confusing if you aren't familiar with the book. And of course, it looks bizarre to modern viewers.

Comment: @AndresF. oh sure, I wasn't arguing with the identification - I thought "Dune" as soon as I read the word "heartplug". I was just quibbling with the OP's characterisation of the film.

Comment: I saw Lynch's _Dune_ before knowing anything about the books.  I followed it and understood it and even liked it.  Then, eventually, I read the books and loved them -- then realized what was so bad about the movie.  It was better before I knew how much it diluted the books and couldn't stand it anymore.

Comment: That sounds like the scene perfectly - thank you. My comments were not that it was definitively low-budget and naff, but that it may not have been a blockbuster movie. And the scene as I remember it could easily have been from a range of tacky films.

Comment: "the Baron is sadistic and homosexual." Quite true but how does the Baron's sexuality have any relevance at all to this question?

Comment: @IgbyLargeman Both attributes are relevant to the scene and help illustrate the Baron's character, since he is inflicting pain on a slave _boy_, and it is implied he derives sexual satisfaction from the act. His homosexuality is a kind of "SF book code" for "perversity" (note: **this isn't my view at all**), but I guess the emphasis is on _sadistic_.

Comment: @AndresF. I think you underestimate SF if you think this code belongs to the genre. You'll find it throughout literature. Indeed sufficiently self aware SF authors can make the feelings of their milieu sufficiently clear that the reader can sense perversity in *things that are normal to them*. Example: the protagonist's view of fixed hetrosexuality in Varley's *The Golden Globe*, or the situation the protagonist of *The Forever War* finds himself in once he assumes his command.

Comment: @dmckee Aaargh, I read many of those books, it's just that I cannot write an elaborate discussion of the portrayal of homosexuality in SF in a _comment_! I meant nothing by my remark except that Frank Herbert's Baron Harkonnen is meant to be homosexual _and_ sadistic, and that those are noticeable traits of his personality, which is meant to be repulsive. Yes, I'm aware other authors portrait homosexuality in a positive light, but in Dune effeminacy/gayness seems to be code for "depraved".

Comment: @AndresF. Check.

Comment: As an aside, it was Thufur Howitt, master of spies for House Atreides that "already received the heart plug", captured during the massacre on Arakis.

Comment: Everyone: some years after I wrote this, I can see how my mentioning of homosexuality might make me seem like a bigot. Since that wasn't my intention, and the problem with the Baron is that he is a sadist and a murderer, not his sexual preferences, I edited out that part. It only took me... what, about 4 years? :P What can I say, I'm stubborn but eventually see the light when I'm wrong ( @IgbyLargeman )

Comment: My only question is, why did you edit his question as well?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Did you read my edit comment? Do you disagree with it?

Comment: @AndresF.: I guess, to me, you took their two questions and then changed it to one based on your answer. That seemed a bit sketchy. But now, thinking it over a bit more, I suppose it makes sense, since it's more likely that people will be trying to figure out the purpose of the heart plugs in Dune than trying to identify the movie with "heart plugs".

Comment: Neither "naff" nor low-budget. It was an ambitious adaptation for its time and has become a cult classic. Although at the time of production it wasn't exactly an A-list cast, almost all of the principals either had or went on to accumulate a notable filmography.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The movie was universally panned when it came out  (Siskel and Ebert even gave it their "Dog of the Year" award). I can see how someone who didn't love the story and wasn't familiar with David Lynch's moviemaking style could mistake it for a low-budget mess with diabolocal acting and no sense of continuity.